# Samba does not work after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, samba, upstart

After upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 from 16.0 Samba does not seem to work.
I did a reinstallation of Samba with a purge but same problem.

If I do

> sudo status smbd

I obtain

> status: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

I tried of course to restart Samba and so on but nothing. If I type

> sudo smbtree

nothing comes out.

I removed and purged samba and did a new installation. I obtain the following error at the end of  apt-get install samba:

```
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked.

/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory
```

Comment: AskUbuntu is a English site. Please rerun your command with `env LANG=C sudo status smbd` so the error message will be printed in English. Edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/947836/edit your Question. Have your read `man samba;man samba-tool;man smb.conf`?

Comment: Changed to English, thanks for that. Tried to read those [man] but I'm a little bit lost I have to say, I just have a vague idea of what is Samba and how it works, I passed some time to try to understand (so that my printer works). Before the upgrade everything was working very fine.